# Как визуализировать двухмерный массив в окно?

Tags: c++, массивы, изображения, интерфейс, визуализация

Есть у меня структура Dot. И есть обычный двухмерный массив под названием map(не std::map) с типом Dot, где первое измерение должно отвечать за X в окне, а второе — за Y; при этом второе измерение считается не сверху вниз, а снизу вверх(мне так удобнее программировать логику).

Мне нужно создать окно и вывести массив туда(желательно, чтоб можно было настраивать размер точки: 1х1, 2х2, т.д.), а в структуре Dot нужно вписать переменную, отвечающую за цвет(я не знаю, как лучше — тремя переменными, каждая отвечающая за цвет, или одной, где просто хранится Hex-код; название переменной я оставлю такое, какое вы у себя в ответе используйте).

Как мне манипулировать картой — потом сам разберусь, подстроюсь под готовое решение.

Comment: То есть по сути вы говорите "посоветуйте библиотеку для работы с графикой". SDL2?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, ну да, но мне также хотелось бы получить готовое решение.

Comment: Ну-ну, лучше идите читайте гайды по SDL2. Работу за других тут обычно не делают.